# Can enums be used in AngularDart templates? How?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

If I have an enum, e.g:

```
@Component(...)
class MyComponent {

    MyEnum myEnum;
    ...
}
```

How can I use this enum in a template? E.g.

```
<div *ngIf="myEnum == MyEnum.SOME_OPTION">
    ...
</div>
```

Edit: I'm specifically interested in how to use enums in comparison.

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/7f6858bc48c1d2a454a4bc350077d67c277c6516/angular/lib/src/core/metadata.dart#L206-L221

> ```
>   /// A list of identifiers that may be referenced in the template.
>   ///
>   /// ## Small Example
>   ///
>   /// Suppose you want to use an enum value in your template:
>   ///
>   ///     enum MyEnum { foo, bar, baz }
>   ///
>   ///     @Component(
>   ///       selector: 'example',
>   ///       exports: const [MyEnum],
>   ///       template: '<p>{{MyEnum.bar}}</p>',
>   ///     )
>   ///     class Example {}
>   ///
>   final List<Object> exports;
> ```

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/master/angular/CHANGELOG.md#new-features-6

Comment: Printing enums works fine, but comparison is a different matter.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion with the template code as you have it in your question?

Comment: Unfortunately the code snippet does not show _comparison_.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. I suppose it's a bit hackish, but it works.

Give the enum a getter that returns a string. Convert the enum in the template to a string by surrounding it with single quotes. Now compare the two strings.

```
String get choice => myEnum.toString();
...
choice == 'MyEnum.SOME_OPTION'
```

Comment: What are the quotes around `MyEnum.SOME_OPTION` for?